# Building Boost Libraries with Android NDK 10 and Clang Toolchain

Tags: c++, boost, android-ndk, clang, llvm-clang

I'm trying to build boost 1.54 with Clang in Android NDK 10e, using following b2 command arguments:

> \b2 --toolset=clang --user-config=./user-config-android.jam
>   cxxflags="-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++
>   -IC:/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include -IC:/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include -IC:/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++abi/libcxxabi/include"
>   linkflags="-stdlib=libc++" threadapi=pthread
>   --prefix=..\boost_android_arm --builddir=./ target-os=linux --with-date_time --with-filesystem --with-regex --with-log define=BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION=3 --with-program_options
>   --with-signals --with-system --with-thread link=static runtime-link=shared threading=multi install

I got lots of errors but initial errors are:

```
C:/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include\string:1371:5: error: unknown type name '_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY_EXCEPT_GCC49'
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY_EXCEPT_GCC49 basic_string()
    ^
C:/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include\string:1371:44: error: member 'basic_string' has the same name as its class
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY_EXCEPT_GCC49 basic_string()
```

I should note that I had successfully built the boost for gcc 4.4. Any help would be appreciated.